# Posting link to another website

Tags: discussion

Getting to the point, is recommending another website in comments each time, considered advertising and spam or not?

Or in even simpler terms, is this against the rules of stack exchange , as it may come under promoting another QA website.

I am only asking about the do's and dont's on this site. I don't how that can be considered as opinion based by everyone.

Comment: Well, having glanced over the tutorial I think I may have found the reason for the [math]...[/math] in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764012/how-can-i-prove-that-there-are-nn2-maps-g-times-g-to-g-where-g-is-a#comment7744456_3764012). (That is, its not entirely relevant which leads to confusion.)

Comment: Also, if you want your question to be taken seriously then don't say "Quora is already more popular than MSE", as this is mostly irrelevant and is likely to make people defensive.

Comment: @user1729, well, facts are facts, though  stack exchange as a whole is more popular than Quora. MSE is not. It was necessary to point out as Google suggests Quora links more than MSE in case of highschool level stuff (my assumption). I do agree it's mostly irrelevant in non-mathematical context. But all I wanted was a YES(I should avoid that) or a NO(it's fine).

Comment: @user1729, I knew about different ways of enabling formatting, so it wasn't a problem for me. Is it alright if I make that clear in my comments? Although, my actual question is still unanswered, can it be considered spam or not?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20-  Math.SE is far far more than just high school math. If all you pay attention to is high school level math, you wouldn't know Google hits for undergrad subjects, e.g., would you?

Comment: @amWhy, I am well aware, I'm only talking with respect to newbies (and most of them without any knowledge of typesetting are undergraduates). that is still irrelevant and is just my one of my supporting points as to why Me recommending another tutorial shouldn't be considered spam. And on top, this question is meant to seek advice so the discussion should be limited to that only.

Comment: I haven't considered your post to be spam, but I consider it opinion based, because you have not argument to support your claims, save for your opinions.  No one has voted to close this as spam.  So just chill a bit.

Comment: @amWhy, No, not that. I'm asking if my Comments can be flagged as spam because questions and answers can (and had been). I posted this question because I want to know the ruling about this and told my opinions as well.  I had a doubt regarding my actions on main site so I asked here, isn't it why meta sites exist?

Comment: Linking to an external website isn't spam. If you were doing this to encourage people to join Quora then it would be spam, and if you posted these comments in pointless places then it would be spam. But the way you are suggesting you use it: no, it's not spam.

Comment: I actually quite like the guide you are linking too, and don't like the MSE guide (it is *very* wordy, as it just a question, and not very "precessional looking", again as it's just a question). However, the introductory section of the Quora guide is so irrelevant that it is misleading. So maybe a better question would be: can we do something like this here?! :-)

Comment: @user1729, I just this did that. I thought explaining the context is necessary but I guess no one understood the actual question in doing so. Thanks for your response and for actually understanding the question. I must say because, you're the only one who did

Comment: Personally, I think your question was fine until the final paragraph, starting "personally". Now your question is unclear to the extent of being unanswerable!

Comment: @user1729, someone commented to explain my points in my previous question so I did that here.

Answer (score -2):

As long as comments are on-topic and obey the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), posting links to other websites is of course allowed.

Comment: In principle, I agree. However, I am worried about the OP's choice of phrase *... each time*. May be I misread the intention, but if they are planning to post the same link dozens of times per day, I would say that's definitely spamming/advertising.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, that is why I asked. Also, I usually prefer brilliant.org over wikipedia.org. though I don't it dozens of times. Mostly because I feel lazy to. I simply edit the question without any questions, as of now.

Comment: "planning to post the same link dozens of times per day" falls into the category of violating CoC.